# Is there a way to compare custom type parameters without turning them to integers first?

Tags: ocaml

For this code block to represent the type *colour* similar to the one in the documentation.

```
type colour =
  | Base
  | Shade of colour
```

Assuming Shade is one unit greater than Base is there a way to compare Shade with Base without first manually converting them to comparable values like integers or float?

Comment: Have you tried just using `compare`, `<`or `>`?

Comment: Yes, since they're of custom types, I couldn't just compare them like that sadly. I guess  I needed to specify their types as the function parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OCaml you can compare any two values of the same type.

```
# Base < Shade Base;;
- : bool = true
#
```

However your type is fairly strange for a color type, so I'm not sure this actually answers your question.

(Your type essentially defines a Peano integer with a base value `Base` and a successor function `Shade`. It doesn't seem much like a color.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wanted to make it looks simpler by keeping the concept the same. I apparently forgot about using Base again and was just comparing Base with Shade without any parameters.